# wiki ROS in Arabic

Tags: ros, ros2, translation, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to add a new language (Arabic) to the main documentation page at
http://wiki.ros.org/
so we can add more tutorials for Arabs users.

I want to work on a translation for the main documentation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/400894/wiki-ros-in-arabic/) by [nadim.arubai](https://answers.ros.org/users/59825/nadim.arubai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 37 on 2022-05-19

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-19**:
Could you check whether #q311848, #q11156 and #q258040 help?

If they do, please close your own question as a duplicate.

**Comment by [nadim.arubai](https://answers.ros.org/users/59825/nadim.arubai/) on 2022-05-20**:
Thanks,

#q311848 helps me in creating 'ar' folder, But there's another issue specific to Arabic:

It's Written Right to Left, and not all text editor fix the problem of writing in 2 languages at same time:

Arabic from Right to Left (RTL), and English from Left to Right (LTR).

So I need help in those:

1> Change the general direction of the page to be from Right to Left.

the edit option only allows adding string with a few other options not including page direction.

2> the ability to write in opposite directions languages RTL and LTR.

I tried Unicode specific characters to force change direction but it failed.

**Comment by [nadim.arubai](https://answers.ros.org/users/59825/nadim.arubai/) on 2022-05-21**:
I managed to switch the direction with dir="rtl" in a few div inside the html template (using inspect command).

But this is on my pc, so how to add it the original template?
and the sidebar also need to be put on the left side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> Change the general direction of the page to be from Right to Left.

At first I thought this wasn't supported by MoinMoin, but apparently you can add `#language ar` to the top of the page and it will cause MoinMoin to render RTL languages correctly (or at least: it will change the text rendering direction to RTL).

Here is a preview of `wiki.ros.org/ar` for instance:

[image: ROS wiki RTL]

As to your other questions: I can only tell you the ROS Wiki is a [MoinMoin instance](http://moinmo.in). So if you want to find out how to do something, try searching for information on how you'd do that with MoinMoin.

Having written that: MoinMoin isn't very actively developed any more afaik, so there is a good chance that some features will not work, or not work entirely as you'd expect or would like.

You'll have to experiment a bit I'm afraid. And probably work around some issues you encounter.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2022-05-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nadim.arubai](https://answers.ros.org/users/59825/nadim.arubai/) on 2022-05-21**:
Thanks, It's worked.

using "#language ar " helps is solving the first part.

I'm searching MoinMoin for the second part, but you can open "wiki.ros.org/ar" to see the problem of bad anchoring the global layout of the text after

ضمان الجودة (انكليزي)

However, changing the float attribute to right , and changing the margin help on my PC.

**Comment by [nadim.arubai](https://answers.ros.org/users/59825/nadim.arubai/) on 2022-05-23**:
I'll consider the problem as solved for now, because the view of 'ar' page is differ with different browser on the same OSs, and differ with the same browser on different OSs. Nevertheless, the texts are readable, so I'll focus on the translation.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-24**:
Please do not close questions if/when they have an accepted answer.

They'll show up as `[closed]` in the question list, while in reality they are answered.

We reserve closing for questions which violate support policies, are off-topic, etc.

**Comment by [nadim.arubai](https://answers.ros.org/users/59825/nadim.arubai/) on 2022-05-25**:
Sorry,

How to reopen it, or have you  already opened it?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2022-05-25**:
No need to apologise.

I've already re-opened it.